# Group mulitiple excel data columns in one chart column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have Excel table like this:
[image: Sample excel table with data]

I would like to create stacked column chart with one column for each year, which is easy. However I want to  group January, February and March and see only Retail and Online parts on columns.

Right now I get something like below, but as you can see it shows it for every month which not needed:
[image]

I am free to reorganize table if needed. Is this possible without creating pivot table with summary data?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do, but possibly you want a column chart that is *both* clustered and stacked (e.g., the stacked bars for online sales are beside the bars for retail sales).  If so, there are instructions on [Peltier's website](https://peltiertech.com/clustered-stacked-column-bar-charts/) that explain how to do it.  Forewarning: it's rather involved.

Answer (score 0):

I would rearrange the data, shown below left.

Data in this layout can be used to make a pivot table, below right, that has year in the row area and segment (retail vs online) in the column area. No need to separate out the months.

This pivot table yields the chart below it.

I copied the pivot table, pasted it below the chart, included the months, and rearranged it a bit, to get the layout of your original data.

[image: Table, Pivot tables, and Chart]

Comment: Thank you Jon. This is desired outcome, only if I could get it from original data, e.g. without pivot step.

Comment: You said you were free to rearrange the data. And the data arrangement to the left of the chart is very flexible, because it its the perfect layout to feed pivot tables, which are truly magical. One pivot table serves as the data range for the chart you wanted, and the other as a display that matches the numerical table you stated with.